# Distributive laws of strong and/or monoidal monads

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

It is well-known that a [commutative strong monad is the same as a monoidal monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+monad).

Is there a notion of distributive law for commutative strong monads which is equivalently a distributive law for monoidal monads?

Does this follow from formal 2-categorical arguments of monads in a bicategory?

Comment: Commutative distributive laws are considered in Wolff's [Commutative distributive laws](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/24190/Wolff_Harvey_1972.pdf), though they do not consider monoidal distributive laws.